# Cassandra 3.11.12 will not start on Windows using cassandra -f

Tags: cassandra

I've downloaded cassandra from apache.cassandra.

I've made sure my env path vars are correctly set.

I type: cassandra -f in a windows command prompt and this is what I get:

```
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:212 char:5
+     $p.Start() | Out-Null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:213 char:5
+     $p.WaitForExit()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:214 char:5
+     $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:218 char:9
+     if ($stderr.Contains("Error"))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:231 char:5
+     $sa = $stderr.Split("""")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:232 char:5
+     $env:JVM_VERSION = $sa[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:234 char:9
+     if ($stderr.Contains("OpenJDK"))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:247 char:5
+     $pa = $sa[1].Split("_")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:248 char:5
+     $subVersion = $pa[1]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\conf\cassandra-env.ps1:406 char:9
+     if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1 -or [convert]::ToI ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The system cannot find the file specified"
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\bin\cassandra.ps1:251 char:9
+         $p.Start() | Out-Null
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.12\bin\cassandra.ps1:253 char:9
+         $p.WaitForExit()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

this is driving me nuts. I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked several times before. There are several known issues with running Cassandra on Windows so support was limited even in earlier versions of Cassandra. We eventually dropped Windows support completely in Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

The recommended workarounds are:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in 5 clicks. Cheers!